# Is there a way to surf previously-visited webpages while offline?

Tags: browser

Is it possible for a browser to remember webpages while surfing, such that when the Internet connection is unavailable/down later, visiting the URLs again will pull out the last-saved version?

I tried the various browsers' "Work Offline" modes but they don't seem to remember much, if at all.  Is there's a setting I've missed? Or something I can install?

Comment: there are different settings for different browsers, but it works only for static pages which are becoming rare...

Comment: Google desktop search indexes web pages you visit. I find the quality of the cached pages somewhat hit and miss though and its no where near as seamless as just using your browser history - Can be useful for retrieving snippets of information though.

Comment: I was hoping of something that'll save ALL previously-visited pages, like some sort of a cache, not just those I purposedly decide to 'save for reading later'.

Comment: Guys, how about running a local Squid?  Has any of you tried Squid for offline browsing?

Comment: @hbdgaf: Than why every browser I have on my computer (IE, FF, Opera) uses hundreds of MBs on disc to store page content? What is the purpose of "setting web cache" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a browser add-on such as **[Read It Later](http://readitlaterlist.com/)** for Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari, etc.  When you add a web page to the Read It Later list, it downloads/prefetches it so you can read it offline...

See the `Offline Options` for Read It Later:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping of something that'll save ALL previously-visited pages, like some sort of a cache, not just those I purposedly decide to 'save for reading later'.

Comment: @William: yes, I know, but I suggested it anyway, in case of a work around or you having a need for special pages being saved...for what it's worth.

Comment: Guys, how about running a local Squid?  Has any of you tried Squid for offline browsing?